# Map Alt Space to Win (Start Menu) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I'm trying to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the Start Menu on Windows 10 (to the same hotkey as Spotlight on Mac). I'm trying to use AutoHotkey, but it's not working:

```
LAlt & Space::LWin
```

Maybe it has something to do with the effects described by [#MenuMaskKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm) blocking LWin from working, so I've tried adding adding a tilde to preserve behavior. But the following doesn't seem to work either:

```
LAlt & Space::~LWin
```

UPDATE - some new examples

```
; WORKS:
3::LWin

; DOESN'T WORK:
!4::LWin

; WORKS:
!5:: RunWait, cmd /k echo hello
```

So, from the above, it appears the `LWin` command does work as a target key, and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does work as a modifier (`!`). Maybe it's the combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>LWin</kbd> that doesn't work.

I think my theory based on reading the above link is that Alt hotkey's get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> added to them to prevent them from activating things like menus. Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LWin</kbd> doesn't bring up the start menu normally, I'm guessing this is the problem.

But I haven't figured out if this can be fixed with the `MenuMaskKey` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that while `Alt` is pressed down, the `LWin` key doesn't have any effect in Windows, apart from anything AHK does. The following solved the problem for me:

```
;Alt interferes with LWin
!Space Up::Send {Alt Up}{LWin}
```